# proxy the port for prerender service

Tags: node.js, prerender

I'm trying to use a local prerender service on my VPS. I set it up successfully on 3999 port. I also included `node-prerender` package in my node backend app, and set the prerender service URL via env variable.

Problem is my app (the SPA that is supposed to be prerendered) is running on port 3000 rather than default 80. When I try to test the prerender service, I call http://mydomain.tld:3000/some/path?_escaped_fragment_= but the port is lost somehow so, as prerender log shows, it tries to query http://mydomain.tld/some/path.

Is there some configuration option that I'm missing? When I try the same query on dev server, e.g. http://my.local.server.ip:3000/some/path?_escaped_fragment_=, the port is successfully passed to prerender.

Comment: I'd suggest getting your app to be displayed correctly through port 80 (or 443 for https) since that's how the crawlers would access your URLs. Then it should work with the Prerender server. Any reason you are using port 3000 in production?

Comment: Thank you for the comment. this is a staging server, and port 80 is used by another app. But if that's the only approach - I'll set it up on default.